# CountDown Method for Android not Working [Edited]

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer, android-asynctask

I am using Android Studio. So this is the full code. I am trying to start the countdown by clicking the startButton. The plan is that the countdown is going down while I can still click the other button. The other button(incrementButton) increments. I got the increment working but the timer is not working when I click the startButton. Is there something wrong I am doing?

**EDIT : Would it also be good to ask on how to cancel the background thread?**
I tried using cancel(true). Changed the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
TextView seconds;
TextView increment;
int count;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    seconds = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seconds);
    increment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.increment);
    Button incrementButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.incrementButton);
    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    Button stopButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    incrementButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.incrementButton:
            count++;
            increment.setText(Integer.toString(count));
            break;
        case R.id.startButton:
            new timerTask();
            break;
        case R.id.stopButton:
            new timerTask().cancel(true);
            break;
    }
}
private void updateSeconds(final int count) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            seconds.setText(Integer.toString(count));
        }
    });
}
public class timerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private int i;
    private int savedSecond;
    public timerTask() {
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            for(i = 10; i > 0; i--){
                savedSecond = i;
                updateSeconds(savedSecond);
                Thread.sleep(1000); //1000 = 1 seconds
                if(isCancelled())
                break;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case R.id.startButton:
        timerTask timerTask  =new timerTask(); // here you created the timer task.
              timerTask.execute() //execute has to be called.
        break;
```

Comment: timerTask here 'T' needs to be capital as it class declaration.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. Thank you, I will do it now :)

Answer (score 2):

Call `execute` method to start `AsyncTask` as:

```
case R.id.startButton:
  new timerTask().execute();
 break;
```

Comment: I literally am laughing my feet off XD Ty.